# Is there any Java Source code obfuscator working on windows 7?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I require a source code obfuscator for Java that is working on windows 7.

Because I plan to release a closed source library in GWT it really has to be an obfuscator that outputs source and does not process ready to use .class files. The result files need to be .java files.

The only obfuscator that is Java-to-Java instead of .class as a result is [Java Source Code Obfuscator](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/obfuscators/JavaObfuscator.html) from Semantic Design.

But sadly it seems this one does not work on Windows 7.

Comment: Why would you need a source code obfuscator? I still don't understand this.

Comment: In an unrelated note: The term "European ASCII" on [this page](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/JavaObfuscator.html?Home=JavaTools) makes me cringe and question the technical capability of the company.

Comment: Hi. I'm the product manager for SD's JavaObfuscator. Can you explain why you think it doesn't work there? We think it does.  It would have been nice if you'd sent a us a note directly outlining your concerns.

Comment: @Joachim: The technical term is ISO8859-1; the "Eurpean ASCII" should be in quotes to indicate it is a sloppy term.  I'll have the web page changed.   However, I think you should check out the rest of the web site before you decide we are incompetent.

Comment: @Ira: don't worry, I was not judging (yes, I've chosen the phrase "question" on purpose). It's just that encoding issues are somewhat of a pet peeve of mine and terminology like that doesn't really help with educating about the issue. (Plus: you've got a definite plus for quick response to customer requests ;-))

Comment: @Joachim: Great. Encoding issues are a pet peeve of ours, too. Our tools work with a wide variety of encodings (ASCII, ISO8859-<several>, Shift-JIS, EBCDIC, many MS code pages); what's listed on that product page was intended to cover the things we thought we of interest to people running Java obfuscators. I'd be happy to send you a document (2 HTML pages) describing the set of encodings we allow (these work for all our tools) and listen specifically to your peeves in an attempt to improve them. See my bio for a contact email, send me yours if you are interested in doing this.

Comment: You could use a decompiler after using a "normal" obfuscator.

Comment: "Because i plan to release a library in gwt it really has to be an
obfuscator that outputs source and does not process ready to use
.class files. The result files need to be .java files."

What do you stand to gain from obfuscating the text in a ".java" file that you plan on making generally available?  And what does this have to do with Windows 7??

Comment: @JoachimSauer we are converting a closed source software to gwt to allow our customers to use gwt as an additional target. That's why we need the source code to be obfuscated.

Comment: @IraBaxter for me the installation did not work. We tested the install on 2 win64 pc's and we thought that the documentation does not contain windows 7 as target os - that's why we didn't contact you directly.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann : that's a nice idea.... we might try that if we don't find a better solution

Comment: @Ocean: Which specific versions of Windows 7 did you try? And can you explain in precise detail what "installation didn't work" is? What exactly happened?  And which Obfuscator did you try (for Java 1.5 or 1.6)?

Comment: @IraBaxter : i tried to install SD_Java~Java1_6_Obfuscator.1.0.12.exe and what happens is that the install claims to be complete but no start menu entry is created. The description in all documentation files that i found describe files that are not created on my harddrive or describe start menu points that are not existing

Comment: @Ocean i have same needs as yours. we have converted closed source java library to a gwt library. In fact more than it. We redesigned the library as gwt safe. Both java and gwt have dependency to this new gwt safe library. I want to obfuscate this gwt safe library. We are using Proguard for Java byte code obfuscation. I tried to decompile the class files by JD-Gui. It has failed at some points. So I think source code obfuscators are more appropriate. But I didn't have one. If you have found a way to obfuscate your library, which tool do you use?

Comment: @user706071 sorry, i did not find a better way. The accepted answer seems to be the best way:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about compile it into class files with all the debugging symbols stripped and then run a decompiler on the resulting class files? [Example decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the existence of some quality work out there, I assure you Java obfuscation will NOT stop someone who is determined to decompile your code. Understand that all you are buying is a bit of time. If they have your class files in hand and choose to decompile them, it won't take long before they have your source code.

If you don't trust your customer, don't give them the class files. Come up with a different solution. More and more companies are moving to services as a way to keep their source code in house and still make their monies.

Comment: in fact a part of our software is a service:) good idea, but because we are developing a communication framework and need to hand our client software we cannot do this.:(

Answer (score -2):

Most Java source codes are self obfuscated, nobody can understand them.

There are no effective obfuscators, the silly things they do do not deter anyone determined to steal your code. This is a false market based on false fears. If the threats were real, there will be de-obfuscators, selling for much higher price than obfuscators.

If you really want to obfuscate your code, don't use meaningless symbols, use misleading symbols.

Comment: If only everyone would respect the property of others, but I know companys that do decompile code and use it regularly.. so this is a true threat to us. Well the idea of using misleading symbols is nice, but the problem is a really big codebase that allready is existing.... and we do not have the time to recode it just to save our intellectual property.